# How to do Firebase query(.equalTo(key))on childListener and map to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a details activity so I am passing DatabaseReference FireKey as getExtras and that is working,I want to query the child and map the data,however **I am getting an error,**

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at graph.app.com.foodgraph.MealDetailsActivity$1.onChildAdded(MealDetailsActivity.java:130)
```

**This is my code**

```
   mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                       Intent i = getIntent();
                       final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey");

                      System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getRef().equalTo(key) + " value is ");
                       ;

                       Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                       if (newPost != null) {
                           reportSingle = new FoodItem(newPost.get("MEAL_TITLE").toString().trim(),
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Have you read the documentation?
If you want to retrieve a `Post` you should navigate to child `posts` (for example) and then add a `ValueListener`. [Follow the documentation on retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a database like the following:

```
{
  "post" : {
    "key01" : {
      "title" : "abc",
      "data" : "def"
    },
    "key02" : {
      "title" : "ghi",
      "data" : "jkl"
    }
  }
}
```

and a Post Class :

```
class Post {
    private String title;
    private String data;

    public Post(){
        // needed for getValue()
    }

    public String getTitle(){return title;}
    public void setTitle(){/*...*/}
    public String getData(){return data;}
    public void setData(){/*...*/}
}
```

In order to retrieve post #1 you then need to do the following:

// get the key here

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("posts").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get Post value
                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                // post now has all the values and
                // can be used to update the UI
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

[Read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

There is no need for a firebase key. If this does not answer your question please rephrase and explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve!

### EDIT

What you should do:

1. Pass the value from another activity like you do right no
2. Navigate your database reference to `...('posts').child(key)`
3. Get the data that's under the key

You database should look like the above example, but instead of `1` or `2`you should use the key.

Comment: I want to fetch data from a child that is equal to key passed from onother class....,

Comment: @VincentMacharia well then this is exactly what you need. You may need to restructure your database, though. see my edit.

Comment: Yah but how do I store snapshot.getRef() to the database so I can use it as child query..,

Comment: What do you mean by child query? a `ChildEventListener`?

Comment: I mean the key should be in the database so that I can use it as a child to orderwith,how do I store the key to the database

Comment: Intent i = getIntent();
               final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey");

      Query queryRef = mDatabase.child("REPORTS")
     .equalTo(key).orderByKey();
      queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       
        Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if (newPost != null) {
         reportSingle = new FoodItem(newPost.get("MEAL_TITLE").toString().trim(),

Comment: Try to invert the query: first order, than filter: `mDatabase.child("REPORTS").orderByKey().equalTo(key)`
The key is already in the database, as a key and that's what orderByKey is for I think

Comment: @VincentMacharia so, did it help?

Comment: No,data snapshot shows null though when I log the key(DatabaseReference key) it has data,I am giving up as I cant see the syntax problem...,If you dont mind I can send you the model class and recyclerView where I am passing the key on recyclerView.setOnClickListener and the detail class for an better insight...,

Comment: System.out.println("The read failed: " +dataSnapshot.toString()); gives System.out: The read failed: DataSnapshot { key = REPORTS, value = null }

Comment: System.out.println("The read failed: " +dataSnapshot.toString()); gives System.out: The read failed: DataSnapshot { key = REPORTS, value = null }...,Meaning its misplacing the child with the key

Comment: @VincentMacharia let's just restart from scratch: You want to load an entity and display it's fields in an activity. Is that right?

Comment: Yes,display all fields in that child.,

Comment: @VincentMacharia well then what you need to do is written exactly in my answer and in the documentation.
You need to create an entity that as the fields you need.
You save the entities in you database as key -> entity.
Then you can retrieve a specific entity by going to `database.child(entityName).child(key)` and parse the entity from the `dataSnapshot` as described above.

Comment: I am getting this err.,Invalid Firebase Database path: https://yyyyy.firebaseio.com/REPORTS/-KK8lg0JS23ObrdRVGB7. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: @VincentMacharia how do you get `DatabaseReference`? `DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` to be sure you are at root you can add `getRoot()` before the first `child()`

Comment: Yes I used String key = mDatabase.child("REPORTS").push().getKey(); and stored it in the database and passed to POJO then I passed in the recyclerView like  foodList.get(position).getFireKey().toString()) did Firebase query like Query reportRef = mDatabase.getReference("REPORTS").child(key).orderByKey();

Comment: What if the value of key is an autogenerated guid which I don't know?